# Why doesn't this SFINAE work as expected?

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++17, type-traits

Okay, why does this C++17 implementation of `is_destructible` not work with reference types? I was hoping that the partial specializations for `T&` and `T&&` would soak up any reference types, but instead, it seems that `int&` is getting caught on the fourth line and [producing a hard error.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nR6ffgNPS08MfLsr)

```
namespace detail {
 template<class T, class Enable> struct is_destructible_impl : false_type {};
 template<class T> struct is_destructible_impl<T&, void>  : true_type {};
 template<class T> struct is_destructible_impl<T&&, void> : true_type {};
 template<class T> struct is_destructible_impl<T, decltype(declval<T&>().~T())> : true_type {};
}

template<class T> struct is_destructible :
    detail::is_destructible_impl<remove_all_extents_t<T>, void> {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_destructible<int&>::value, "oops");
}
```

What is it that makes the compiler prefer to match `<int&, void>` against `<T, (complicated expression that fails)>` instead of against that tempting `<T&, void>`?

**UPDATE:** It turns out that this is a GCC bug. Clang accepts the code just fine. So, follow-up question: is there a workaround that would make something like this `is_destructible` work on GCC without too much extra coding?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that GCC - incorrectly - emits a hard error on a mismatched pseudodestructor call.

```
template<class T, class U>
auto f(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T&>().~U());

template<class T, class U>
int f(double);

using t = decltype(f<int, double>(0));

struct C {}; struct D {};
using tt = decltype(f<C, D>(0));
```

GCC emits a similar error with `t` but not `tt`.

Clang compiles your code just fine.

---

> is there a workaround that would make something like this
>   `is_destructible` work on GCC without too much extra coding?

Just move the reference specializations out:

```
namespace detail {
 template<class T, class Enable> struct is_destructible_impl : false_type {};
 template<class T> struct is_destructible_impl<T, decltype(declval<T&>().~T())> : true_type {};
}

template<class T> struct is_destructible :
    detail::is_destructible_impl<remove_all_extents_t<T>, void> {};
template<class T> struct is_destructible<T&>  : true_type {};
template<class T> struct is_destructible<T&&> : true_type {};
```